# Overwriting Styling using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

What I'm trying to do is whenever I click my input field in my Sign Form I want the form to look like this.

[image]

I'm currently achieving the above result by using the ...:hover on the div element (#my-sub-container-02) that contains the entire form (it is commented out in the code given below). What I want to do is (along with hover), the blackish background should appear whenever I have any of my input fields focused (clicked and cursor is waiting for a user input).

I tackled the problem trying to use JavaScript(JS). In JS I tried using the approach that whenever I click any of my input field it should style the background of my div to appear in the first screen shot I have given. Please note in the JS file I have written below I am currently only working with the first input field that is of First Name. I specifically gave it an ID to make things in JS easier. I have not fiddled with the other input fields as of yet.

I can tell you this much that the JS file till onclick is working, that is, on clicking the first input field the "transition" function is being called successfully. You can substitute these IDs to make sure "my-sub-container-01" (This is for the text on the left side of form) and "my-sub-container-02-submit" (Text "submit" on the button below the form). If either of the above IDs were used in the substitution then the respective element for each of the IDs' font color should turn "red" when the first input field (First Name) is clicked upon.

However, whenever I try to use styling on signup form nothing changes. )The current ID in the JS file is for the signup form.)

If I should not be using JS for this problem at all could you please guide to what I should use. I'll make sure to tackle that on my own before asking for help again.

The HTML, CSS and JS file is as below. I am also using a few classes from Bootstrap but I'm not putting it up b/c of humongous length of the file. (http://getbootstrap.com)

*Reminder: The paths to the CSS/JS/Images are set according as to how I have them on my system.*

HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="site-hd container">
    <h1>F U N G&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspE N T R Y&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspT E S T</h1>
</div>
<div id="my-container-01">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-6 col-m-12" id="my-sub-container-01">
            <h2>Are you looking the best way to prepare your Entrance Test Exam?</h2>
            <p id="my-sub-container-text-01">This website is your complete resource to get admission in the top ranked universities of Pakistan. Our team consists of toppers from several universities. We have collected more than 2000 MCQs from Past Papers of NUST, MCAT, GIKI, PIEAS and FAST, over the last three years and are making them available to you through this platform. Join us for practicing past paper MCQs, getting tips from the toppers, learning tricks to solve MCQs and having sincere advice at each stage of your entry test.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-m-12" id="my-sub-container-02">
            <h2 id="my-sub-container-hd-02">Sign Up</h2>
            <form id="my-sub-container-02-signupform" name="SingupForm">
                <div>
                  <input class="my-sub-container-02-input" id="Test" type="Name" name="FName" placeholder="Enter First Name">
                  <input class="my-sub-container-02-input" type="Name" name="LName" placeholder="Enter Last Name";>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input class="my-sub-container-02-input" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input class="my-sub-container-02-input" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Enter password">
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label class="my-sub-container-02-label"><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                </div>
                <button id="my-sub-container-02-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <p>Something something</p>
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* 
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*The columns inside a row are all floating to the left, and 
are therefore taken out of the flow of the page, and other 
elements will be placed as if the columns do not exist. To 
prevent this, we will add a style that clears the flow:*/

.site-hd
{
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    text-align: center;
}

#my-container-01
{
    background-image: url("../Images/pexels-photo-176851.jpeg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#my-sub-container-01
{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-align: justify;
}

#my-sub-container-text-01
{
    font-size: 20px;
}

#my-sub-container-02
{
    margin-top: 40px;
    transition: ease-in 1s;
}

/*#my-sub-container-02:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}*/

#my-sub-container-hd-02
{
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
    margin-left: 30%;
}

.my-sub-container-02-input
{
    margin: 20px 35px 15px 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #272822;
    color: white;
}

.my-sub-container-02-input:focus
{
    outline: none !important;
}

.my-sub-container-02-label
{
    margin: 20px 35px 15px 44px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}

#my-sub-container-02-submit
{
    margin-left: 40%;
    padding: 8px 25px 8px 25px;
    border: 2px solid #00689d;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #8bac39;
    /*background: -o-radial-gradient(circle, red, yellow, green); /* Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
    font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.row
{
    width: 100%
}

.row::after 
{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}


[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
    padding: 15px;
}


[class*="col-"] 
{
    /*mobile*/
    width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    /* For tablets: */
    .col-m-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-m-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-m-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-m-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-m-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-m-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-m-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-m-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-m-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-m-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-m-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-m-12 {width: 100%;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    /* For desktop: */
    .col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
    .col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
    .col-3 {width: 25%;}
    .col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
    .col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
    .col-6 {width: 50%;}
    .col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
    .col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
    .col-9 {width: 75%;}
    .col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
    .col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
    .col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

JavaScript

```
"Use Strict"
// Declarations on Top
// It is a good coding practice to put all declarations at the top of each script or function.

// This will:

// Give cleaner code
// Provide a single place to look for local variables
// Make it easier to avoid unwanted (implied) global variables
// Reduce the possibility of unwanted re-declarations


function validateForm() 
{


    var a, b, c, d;
    a = document.forms["SingupForm"]["FName"].value;
    b = document.forms["SingupForm"]["LName"].value;
    c = document.forms["SingupForm"]["Email"].value;
    d = document.forms["SingupForm"]["Password"].value;
    if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "" || d == "") 
    {
        if (a == "")
            alert("First Name field must be filled out");
        else if (b == "")
            alert("Last Name field must be filled out");
        else if (c == "")
            alert("Email field must be filled out");
        else if (d == "")
            alert("Password field must be filled out")
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Form successfully submitted"); 
        // onclick(document.getElementById("sub-btn").innerHTML = "<a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>");
    }
}

function transition()
{
    document.getElementById("my-sub-container-02-signupform").style.color="red";
}

function init()
{
    var SignUpForm;

    SignUpForm = document.getElementById("my-sub-container-02-signupform");
    SignUpForm.onsubmit = validateForm;

    var translation;

    translation = document.getElementById("Test");
    translation.onclick = transition;
}

window.onload = init();
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `:focus` selector in CSS? When you click a button, it receives focus and you can define how it looks in CSS.

Comment: have you tried using :focus in css instead of approaching it from the JS side

Comment: Yes I have. Using focus on the form doesn't work and using focus on the input field isn't what I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: Closing your input tags is useful. Not necessary, but at the very least _consistent_. A tag that is not closed is easy to identify that way. You can choose to go either way, but it's safe to use best practise and close them. Same goes for quoting attribute values, but you already did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a simple bit of javascript to change the class of your form when the input receives focus like this:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

// Simply listen for the focus event on your input and change the class
// You could also directly change styles with form.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
input.addEventListener('focus', function(){
  form.className = 'focused';
});
input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
  form.className = '';
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
form.focused {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="input" />
</form>
```

You could also do it for multiple `input` elements by selecting them all (my example assumes all the inputs are inside your form, but otherwise just use css selectors queries like `#myFormId input`) and apply it to all:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ){
  inputs[i].addEventListener('focus', function(){
    form.className = 'focused';
  });
  inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', function(){
    form.className = '';
  });
}
```

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
form.focused {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I had absolutely forgotten about the EventListener(). Now I need to go look at whats happening to my styling when the black background appears (its going haywire). Thanks a bunch! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The [CSS `:focus` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) can take care of this quite easily.

```js
btn = document.getElementById('order');
wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  // Show the form
  wrapper.style.display = "block";  
});
```

```css
/* Don't show the form initially */
#wrapper { display:none; }

/* Style all div elements to have a colored background and size */
div {position:relative; background: #808080; width:75%;padding:10px;}

/* Set the initial color of the form and the input fields */
wrapper:hover, input {background:#808080;}


/* Change the color of the input fields when the are focused */
/*
input:focus { background:#808080; 
              /* Transition added just for fun */
              transition: background 1s;
}
*/
```

```html
<button id=order>Place Order</button>
<div id=wrapper>
  <form>
    <input type=text>
    <input type=text>
    <br>
    <input type=text>
    <input type=text>
    <br>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should close your input tags properly and use the quotation marks, if only for best practise... `<input type="text" />`

Comment: The self-terminating syntax is only appropriate for XHTML and the quotes are only necessary when values contain spaces. The code is 100% HTML5 valid. Quite frankly, even the `type=text` is not required in HTML5.

Comment: Great stuff, Scott, but best practise does not agree. You shouldn't focus on the exceptions, this is a site where people learn and you should not get them started with bad habbits.

Comment: I agree with @somethinghere. It is good practice to keep HTML 5 well-formed and attribute values quoted.

Comment: Actually, that's incorrect. There is no accepted form on this, except to say that consistency is the best, best practice. (BTW, I have been writing and teaching HTML for 20 years and am just a little bit knowledgeable about this).

Comment: Very good Scott, I don't understand why you consider teaching people things that could become an issue instead of teaching them bullet proof ways. Its great you know the exceptions and details, but for casual users this is confusing and dangerous.

Comment: On top of that, it is really bad practice to use the short-hand property `background` if all you want to do is change `background-color`.

Comment: @somethinghere Bulletproof? Do you know how many times I've seen this: `<script src=urlHere />` and then had questions about why the page is blank?  Using self-terminating elements is not bullet-proof and leads to the incorrect usage of them. Unless you are writing XHTML (and really, who is doing that anymore?) it is just more characters to type and opens up the opportunity for problems. That is not a best-practice.

Comment: _It is bulletproof for input elements_. Using quotations is _bulletproof for strings with spaces AND without spaces_. I really don't see why you insist on using shorthand syntaxes that can go wrong in many places. _Not closing a script tag is not the same_ and was **not** what I was saying.

Comment: Your example advocates exactly the opposite of what you're claiming. Knowing which elements must be closed as opposed to e.g. `p` and `li` which in HTML 5 don't *require* closing is far more confusing for beginners than to understand what is the difference between elements that can have `content` in contrast to those that cannot have content.

Comment: So, we are going to scrutinize each line of code in every SO answer. Is that what we're doing now? Does my post answer the question: *"What I want to do is (along with hover), the blackish background should appear whenever I have any of my input fields focused (clicked and cursor is waiting for a user input)."*?

Comment: Yeah, good comment reading you did there. Mate, this is a site where people learn a lot of stuff. If you are going to condone teaching them that things might explode at any time, then that seems like a bad idea. And this got kind of out of hand, to be honest. I know it's a small thing and I only wanted to mention it because it would make life easier for those who dont know all the intricacies of HTML yet.

Comment: @ScottMarcus okay so I already tried using input:focus but input:focus {background-color: black}. However, using focus on the "input" determines the background color only for the input field I have currently chosen. It does not color the background of the whole sign up form like in the screen shot posted.

Comment: Also regarding other comments I'll keep in mind closing the input tags properly. I was not aware that input tags were required to be closed and I will keep in mind the quotation marks.

Comment: @HaroonRamay I am a bit outnumbered here, but the `input` element is NOT required to be closed. The code I've shown is  100% valid in all HTML5 browsers (which is all browsers within the last 1.5 years). Trust me, you will be better off NOT adding these. They are a holdover from the days of an XML flavor of HTML called XHTML and, while they do not adversely affect your code and are valid, they are also not required and your code is valid without them. Take a look at this Mozilla Developer Network link, showing them not closed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: @HaroonRamay All you need to do is change the CSS selector from `input:focus` to get the whole form to change when it is interacted with. The CSS selector (the part prior to the `{}` is what will be affected by the rule (the part inside the `{}`). I have updated my answer to show multiple selectors.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for the effort but I'm not looking to add background to the input fields. I wanted to add the background to whole form so it kinda pops up when you're filling it. Like in the screen shot. The form is highlighted when hovering over the div element but I wanted to keep the same back ground when the input field are focused. So that the background remains on the div even if I remove my mouse. Thanks though ^^ Cheers

Comment: @HaroonRamay I would suggest you spend more time investigating CSS. I've given you everything you need to get what you want. It's just that a screen shot doesn't tell us when things happen. Adjusting the color of my CSS rule solves the issue. Is it correct to say that you just want the form and all the inputs to have a colored background as soon as the form comes up and the color should just stay that way?

Comment: @ScottMarcus If you perhaps you looked at the answer that helped me solve the problem maybe that'll clear the air about what I wanted because it seems I am unable to explain what is it I wanted in a clear manner. Cheers.